# What can I do when part of my text in my textview is not showing up?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I am using this textview inside a linear layout (note: this code is inside some other layout):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I rotate the screen of the android device to landscape, part of the text (the second line) in the textview is cut off.

What can I do to fix that??

Comment: When I try your code, everything works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different layout resource file for landscape mode. More here:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html